# How can I adapt a c# class with private methods?

Tags: c#, command, private, adapter

I would like to adapt a class with a private method, so that the adapter calls this private method:

Consider this class

```
public class Foo
{
   private void bar()
}
```

I would like a class that follows the command pattern, and calls bar() in it's execute method:

```
public class FooCommand
{
   private Foo foo_;
   public FooCommand(Foo foo)
   {
      foo_ = foo;
   }
   public void execute()
   {
      foo.bar();
   }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are many options:

- Instead of a `FooCommand`, use an interface `ICommand` with an `Execute` method. Then declare `Foo` in such a way that it implements `ICommand`:

  ```
  public class Foo : ICommand {
      private void bar() { ... }
      void ICommand.Execute() { bar(); }
  }
  ```

  I believe this is the most attractive solution: the method can still be private; you don’t need to instantiate an extra `FooCommand` for every `Foo`; and you don’t need to declare a separate `XCommand` class for every `X` class that wants it.
- Declare the `FooCommand` class inside the `Foo` class so that it becomes a *nested class*. Then the `FooCommand` can access the private method.
- Declare the `bar` method *public* or *internal*.
- Declare the `bar` method *protected* or *protected internal* and then derive `FooCommand` from `Foo`.
- Use Reflection to invoke the private method (use [`Type.GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) followed by [`MethodBase.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx)). I believe most developers would consider this a dirty hack.

Comment: Thanks, Timwi. I like the nested class approach, but I need to reference this nested class from outside Foo. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jacko: If it’s public, yeah, sure.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to at least make bar() protected rather than private. Private functions can only be called by the class that declares them, unless you decide to use Reflection which then places security requirements on your application.

Comment: Thanks, Jeffrey. I don't want to inherit from Foo, in which case protected would be useful, but rather to wrap it in another class.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this would be to use reflection and invoke the method that way, however I would strongly suggest against doing that. Why not just make the method internal?

Comment: Thanks, BFree. Using internal would degrade the encapsulation on this method, so I am looking for a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
   public void execute()
   {
       var m = foo_.GetType().GetMethod("bar", BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
       m.Invoke(foo_, null);

   }
```

I agree with the other posters who say make the method internal and use InternalsVisibleToAttribute if needed.

Comment: Thanks, Preet. But, I am a bit hesitant about using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to class Foo as in access to modify the class? If not, I don't believe you can call its private method bar() from another class.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I do have access to class Foo.